# Understanding the makeup of an XML .ev3p file

Tags: ev3

When you unzip an `.ev3` program, there are many `txt` and `xml` files that are inside. In particular, there is an `xml` file produced with the filename extension `.ev3p`, which seems to contain program instructions which the EV3 brick can then interpret and execute. I am interested in using these `.ev3p` files produced in order to analyze the correctness of programs.

To test this, I created two `.ev3` programs: one which moves forward 3 cycles, one which moves forward 5 cycles. Upon text-comparing their respective `.ev3p` files, I found :

```
<ConfigurableMethodTerminal ConfiguredValue="3">
```

in the first file and

```
<ConfigurableMethodTerminal ConfiguredValue="5">
```

in the second file.

However, there are other small, unexplained differences between the respective `.ev3p` files. I need to know:

- Is there any documentation that is provided by National Instruments that can give me insight into how these `.ev3p` files are produced and how they can be interpreted.

Answer (score 10):

I personally doubt that there is any publicly available documentation of the contents of these files. However, you may gain some insight from the documentation in the "EV3 Block Developer Kit" available on the [LEGO MINDSTORMS Download](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads) page.

Tip: rather than using the outdated copy of the EV3 software included in the EV3 Block Developer Kit, I have found that you can create a file named `MindstormsEV3.ini` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Tokens DeveloperMode="True" />
```

and save it in the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 program directory to enable developer mode on any installed version of the software.

Comment: Do you know if the developer mode can be enabled on the macOS version of the EV3 software? I tried creating an INI file per your instructions and saved it in the Content folder in the app's package. I didn't see anything obvious indicating a "developer mode."

Comment: It needs to be in the same folder as `MindstormsEV3.exe` (the `MonoBundle` folder on macOS).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "developer mode"? What happens when you enable it?