# Converting a .ev3p file into a .ev3 project file

Tags: ev3

How do I convert a `.ev3p` file into a `.ev3` project file?  Everytime I click on the `.ev3p` file to open it, it just turns up as text in the notepad.

Comment: This sounds like a file association problem at your OS-level.  How to fix this will change depending on whether you're on Windows, MacOS, etc.  Renaming the file may fix it, but it depends on the associations that you have and those could change from PC to PC.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, you can't convert the ev3p file to an ev3 file. However, you can put your ev3p file into a zip, then rename the extension to .ev3s
After this, you can create a new project, and from the settings tab, import your ev3s file.
[image: The settings tab]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **can't** convert a `.ev3p` file into a `.ev3` file. Based on [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/understanding-the-makeup-of-an-xml-ev3p-file?rq=1) and other ones here's what a `.ev3p` file *really* is:

> When you unzip a `.ev3` program, there are many `txt` and `xml` files that are inside. In particular, there is an `xml` file produced with the filename extension `.ev3p`, which contains program instructions that the EV3 brick can then interpret and execute.

So now we can conclude that a `.ev3p` file is only **a certain part** of the `.ev3` file.